# Is that good practice to use iframe

Tags: html, iframe

Need some advice to use iframe for widget or not.
Will some addons/plugin block the IFrame in browsers?

Comment: iframes are contained. No plugins that I know of will disable them, unless the plugin rewrites the dom of the parent.

Comment: Iframes are all over the place - Youtube embeds, Facebook like boxes, third-party commenting systems...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of IFrames for me has no adverse effects.

All the big companies use IFrames for Ad serving, Widgets. We use Iframe for delayed download of a file.

There are heaps of use cases to use IFrames so its not as bad as it sounds. I never came across any plugin or add-on which blocks IFrames.

Even though you can do pretty much everything using Javascript too but end of the day IFrames allows more control over the content I would say.

Answer (score 1):

iframes are pretty common. one example of a popular use is the facebook like button. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/